# SELECT SQLite.NET records where IDs match int array

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using SQLite.NET. I am trying to pass an integer array to a search query. I would like to return a list of records where the IDs (table attributes) match the integers in an array. The array is of size 10.

In MainPage.cs:

```
int[] arr  = new int[10];
// for testing purposes    
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++{
  arr[i] = i;
}

var selected = App.Database.SearchList(arr);
```

In SQLiteDatabase.cs:

```
public List<Rooms> SearchList(int[] ID)
{
     return database.Query<Rooms>("SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID = ?;", ID);
}
```

This results in the following error when the query is executed:

> System.NotSupportedException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details

How can I return a list of records where the IDs match? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `IN` keyword

```
WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I make it so I can pass the array into the query? I have tried this `return database.Query<Rooms>("SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID IN ?;", arr);` However, this results in this error: SQLite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error.

Comment: That's about $"SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID IN ({string.Join(",", arr)})"

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 1 `'?'` per argument so you can create your query string like this:

`string query = $"SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID IN ({string.Join(",", IDs.Select(x => "?"))});"`

This makes the `IN` clause like `(?,?,...,?)`

Then when calling `Query` its necessary to cast the arguments to an object array or you'll get the exception as mentioned by @Neil B like this:

`return database.Query<Rooms>(query,IDs.Cast<object>().ToArray());`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently SQLite.NET does not support passing in an array as a parameter.

This throws and exception:

```
var IDs = new[] { 1, 2 };
return database.Query<Rooms>("SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID IN (?);", IDs);
```

In this case the only solution is to join the paramters in the SQL string. This works for int[], but when using strings you should beware of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
var IDs = new[] { 1, 2 };
return database.Query<Rooms>($"SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID IN ({string.Join(",", IDs)});");
```

Comment: This isn't really scalable unfortunately. It would be better if SQLite.NET created a temporary table with the input values (at least if they exceed a certian quantity) and did the inserts and then an inner join under the hood. Alas.